# How can I make my shell script detect a state change across multiple invocations?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using the following "script" to monitor a Port on a Server:

```
l_TELNET=`echo "quit" | telnet server.domain.tld 12345 | grep "Escape character is"`
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT failed"
    #Something happens here if Service (port) down
  exit 1
else
    #Something happens here if Service (port) up
  exit 0
fi
```

How can I modify this to only execute the "Service down" section the *first* time a service is detected to be down (until it's next back up), as opposed to every five minutes while the service continues to be down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using temp files?

```
l_TELNET=`echo "quit" | telnet server.domain.tld 12345 | grep "Escape character is"`
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    if  [ ! -f /tmp/12345down]; then
        echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT failed"
        #Something happens here if Service (port) down
        touch /tmp/12345down
        exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
else 
    #Something happens here if Service (port) up
    if  [ -f /tmp/12345down]; then
        rm -f /tmp/12345down
    fi
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Vlad!